# Преобразование запроса из mysql в формат Eloquent ORM Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Как написать такой запрос

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM `drivers` where 
         user_id = 1 order by trawel_date desc LIMIT 10) as tmp
  where (way1 = 25 or way2 = 25 or way3 = 25 )
```

при помощи конструктора запросов Laravel 5?
 Не могу разобраться, как заменить FROM. Конструирование запроса начинается с `$this->drivers` а это эквивалентно `SELECT * FROM drivers`. Пробовал через `DB::raw` передавать внутренний `SELECT` - не работает. И пробовал так

```
$tmp = $this->drivers->latest('trawel_date')
        ->where('user_id', '=', 1)->take(10)->get();
return $tmp->where('way1','=',25)
                    ->orwhere('n2','=',25)
                    ->orwhere('n3','=',25)->count();
```

ошибка получается. Вообще, возможно сконструировать такой запрос? Уж очень не хочется оставлять запрос в таком виде. Хотелось бы красиво, по-laravel-овски :)

Comment: Было бы славно, если бы вы указали какая именно ошибка получается.

Comment: Call to undefined method `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orwhere()` она из-за того, что возвращается коллекция.

Answer (score 1):

Конструирование запроса начинается с

```
$tmp = Drivers::latest(..)->...
```

Кроме того

```
$tmp->where(..)->..
```

уже сделать нельзя так как tmp уже является коллекцией после выполнения `get()`, а вам нужен `Builder`. Т.е. либо делаете запрос с начала, либо например так:

```
 $tmp = Drivers::latest('trawel_date')
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->take(10);
 $result = $tmp->get();
 return $tmp->where('way1', 25)
     ->orWhere('n2', 25)
     ->orWhere('n3', 25)
     ->count();
```

**UPD**

Также можно фильтровать по n1, n2, n3 уже полученную коллекцию

```
 $tmp = Drivers::latest('trawel_date')
    ->where('user_id', 1)
    ->take(10)->get();

 $result = $tmp->filter(function ($driver) {
     return ($driver->n1 == 25 || $driver->n2 == 25 || $driver->n3 == 25);
 });

 return $result->count();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но, дело в том, что условия orwhere мне нужно применять именно к 10-ти отобранным строкам, которые в $result находятся. Получается выход только один - в foreach обрабатывать $result?

Comment: исправила запрос

Comment: Вас не смущает, что должно быть `orWhere`?

Comment: Неверно считает. `\DB::listen(function($sql) {
   var_dump($sql);
  });` показывает вот что `select * from drivers where user_id = ? order by travel_date desc limit 10` и `select count(*) as aggregate from drivers where user_id = ? and n1 = ? or n2 = ? or n3 = ? order by travel_date desc limit 10` и ответ  = 181 а должно быть 3

Comment: обновила ответ, попробуйте версию ниже